# Best way to keep WebSocket connection alive in Akka HTTP?

Tags: java, scala, websocket, akka, akka-http

If there is no message sent or received, the connection is closed after one minute.

I don't want to continuously send a text message to keep the connection open like this:

```
keepAlive(maxIdle = 10.seconds, () => TextMessage.Strict("Keep-alive message")
```

Is there anything in Akka HTTP that provides the natural sending of ping/pong messages? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to manually use the `keepAlive` combinator, then you can use Akka HTTP's automatic keep-alive ping support, which is enabled via settings in your `application.conf`.

For the [client side](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/websocket-support.html#automatic-keep-alive-ping-support):

```
akka.http.client.websocket.periodic-keep-alive-max-idle = 10 seconds
```

For the [server side](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/server-side/websocket-support.html#automatic-keep-alive-ping-support):

```
akka.http.server.websocket.periodic-keep-alive-max-idle = 10 seconds
```

More information is in the linked documentation.

Comment: Is it enough to enable this server side? I think when server sends pings, client should be respondings with pongs and it should work. Can you please clarify?